# What's wrong with my `adb logcat ...` command?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I just want to see `logcat` output for `MyTag` that my app outputs.  I thought this would be the command to run ...

```
$ adb logcat MyTag:*
```

... but nothing gets filtered and the output is the same as if I had executed:

```
$ adb logcat
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you are on mac/linux, try adb logcat | grep MyTag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me :

**`adb logcat -s MyTag`**

**EDIT :**

The format that you are trying is more like

**`adb logcat *:s MyTag`**

Comment: To expand on this, the "MyTag:<level>" option means to set the level for your tag, while leaving all other tags unchanged. You could have added "*:S" to silence all other tags. The "-s" option is just a shortcut for "*:S"

Comment: @EdwardFalk :Thanks for the explanation! :)